# Hide input by using input array name index with css

Tags: html, css, arrays

i have an html structure like this:

```
<input class="swatch-input super-attribute-select" name="super_attribute[141]" type="text" value="" data-selector="super_attribute[141]" data-validate="{required: true}" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

i need to hide it by using input name, the problem is the input name is an array, i need to hide it for specific array index. i've tried like this:

```
input[name="super_attribute[141]"] {display: none !important;}
```

but it's not working at all

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Can you inspect in the console and look for conflicts?

Comment: It is working fine for me too. Can you re-check in browser console to make ensure that rendering input like as you mentioned above?